# VSTS: Release Management Deploying Artifacts to IIS on Premise

Tags: azure-devops, msdeploy, autorelease, ms-release-management, azure-pipelines

I am using VSTS Release management to deploy artifacts to IIS websites. I have several Web applications and web services to be deployed. So, i am trying to figure out what sort of tasks that best fits my situation.

I have created a build definition with Visual Studio Build Task for projects as this one:
[image]

which works fine but i need to add a task for copying the artifacts Under IIS Website Directory.

The other approach is to use IIS web deployment as a task in Release definition, so I created the build definition as:

[image]

However, it expects a Publish Profile (the build fails because it can't find it). I don't need to create a publish profile for each project in the application because this would be too much work.

Is there is a workaround for that or what is preferred approach for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update your build definition to generate a web deployment package and upload it to artifacts. And then in Release Management, add a task to run "projectname.deploy.cmd" in the deployment package to deploy it to your IIS server. Refer to this link for details: [How to: Install a Deployment Package Using the deploy.cmd File Created by Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356104(v=vs.110).aspx).

And you can also enable [FTP Publishing](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/adding-ftp-publishing-to-a-web-site-in-iis-7) on your IIS server and add a task in your release to publish the artifacts via FTP. You may need this task: 
[FTP Uploader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=januskamphansen.ftpupload-task).

Answer (score 3):

My [Continuous Delivery with TFS / VSTS – Server Configuration and Application Deployment with Release Management](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-tfs-vsts-server-configuration-application-deployment-release-management/) blog post (with reference to some previous posts) has all the details you need for deploying your artefacts to target nodes using **Windows Machine File Copy** tasks then use **PowerShell on Target Machines** tasks to get them in to correct locations and to do token replacement and anything else that's required.

I would recommend using PowerShell DSC so that IIS is properly configured before deployment but that's not required. Where possible for web apps I favour keeping things very simple by creating artefacts that contain all the web files that are needed for a particular folder and then just using plain xcopy for the deployment.

Answer (score 2):

If you need more control you can also use my MSDeploy VSTS extension to deploy a MSDeploy package

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rschiefer.MSDeployAllTheThings

https://dotnetcatch.com/2016/04/20/msdeployallthethings-vststfs-extension-is-public/